# PHP - Display argument typed in URL

Tags: php, url, arguments

I have juste started learning PHP and I don't know how I can display arguments' names and values passed in URL, for instance if type http://myadress.php?name=steve&age=15, I would like it to display :

name: steve
age : 15

Here is what I have tried with no success, it won't even get into the loop :-(

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    echo "Test ";
    echo "i = $i";
    while (isset($argv[$i]))
    {
        echo $_GET[$argv[$i]];
            $i++;
    }
    echo "i = $i"; 
?>
```

Comment: consider accepting my answer to prevent this question from getting more unneeded attention, or if my answer didn't solve your problem, use the comments section to ask for further detail.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the `$_GET` parameters using a simple `foreach` and print their keys and values appropriately.

```
foreach($_GET as $k=>$v)
{
    echo $k." : ".$v."<br>";
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
name : steve
age : 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguments passed via [HTTP GET](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) (as Arguments in the URL seperated by & and sepearated from the url by ?) will be available in your PHP code via `$_GET`.

If in a Form you use POST to send data it will be `$_POST`.

Both Values always also appear in `$_REQUEST`.

Those are all arrays so you can acces your variables/parameters by their respective names.
In your Example:

*http://example.org/test.php?name=steve&age=15*

```
<?php
  /* your test.php file*/
  echo 'name: '.$_GET['steve'].' age : '.$_GET['age'].'';
```

This will output, as requested:

```
name : steve age 15
```

To iterate over those arrays you can use [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) as mentioned in the other answer.